# kohana ORM error

Tags: php, kohana

I have a db table called "packs" (pack_id, pack_name, pack_description, pack_image)

My packs.php model:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

    class Model_Packs extends ORM {

    }
```

My packs.php controller:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Packs extends Controller {

    public function action_index($pack_name = null)
    {
        $view = new View('packs/index');                        
        $this->response->body($view); 
    }   

    public function action_pack()
    {
        $pack_name = $this->request->param('id'); //get the packname from uri

        $pack = ORM::factory('packs')->where('pack_name', $pack_name)->find();
        print_r($pack);die;

        $view = new View('packs/index'); 

        $this->response->body($view); 
    }   
} // End of file
```

Calling www.mysite.com/packs/pack/aPackName , Kohana throws this error:

Database_Exception [ 1146 ]: Table 'packs_db.packses' doesn't exist [ SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM 'packses' ]

I checked my database.php conf file, everything's ok.
Why da hell is kohana adding "es" at the end of the table name?? I am completely puzzled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems kohana is trying to be "smart" and guess what's the table name based on class name.
if you rename your model to `Model_Pack` It should do the trick. Other solution is to give your model [table name](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm).

Answer (score 1):

Your model should be named in singular noun `Model_Pack` even though your table name is in plural. Those two rules are parts of [Kohana ORM conventions](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm/starting#orm_conventions).

p/s: the link points to conventions for Kohana 2.x but they are still applicable for 3.x with a few modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Also had this problem, one of the solutions I found is to restrict set _table_names_plural variable to false. Something like this:

```
class Model_Admin_Users extends ORM 
  {
  public function __construct()
    {
    $this->_table_names_plural = false;
    parent::__construct();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes you're right, and another, even more simple solution, is to override the table_name attribute.
protected $_tablename = "whatever_you_want";